# C# - Simple Validation - DialogResult

Tags: c#

I have the following code for a button click on a form:

```
        private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        if (this.txtProjectName.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No project name entered", "No Project Name", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            btnOK.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
        }
        else
        {
            this.btnOK.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            return;
        }
    }
```

If there is something in the text box, the form will only close on the second click.  Is there a way to close the form instantly, and pass a DialogResult.OK to it's caller?

Thanks

Comment: closing the form can be achieved by calling this.Close() - something that is missing here anyway. Though GvS is also right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of setting the `this.btnOK.DialogResult`, use this:

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

This will set the [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult) of the Form. The form will close, and DialogResult will have its correct value.

Comment: I had never noticed that just setting the DialogResult property would close the Form, I always thought you had to call Me.Close() afterwards. Well, I'll win one line of code now, thanks! :D

Comment: This is only true for Modal Dialog Boxes:"If the form is displayed as a dialog box, setting this property with a value from the DialogResult  enumeration sets the value of the dialog box result for the form, hides the modal dialog box, and returns control to the calling form. " see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx

Comment: @GvS Will your suggestion work even if you have the OK button's DialogResult set to "OK" in the designer?  I want to be able to override this with validation in my source code.